# oracle decode group by warning

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have this code

```
for x_eo in ( select decode(mod(card_name_id,2),0,1,1,2) e_o, count(*) nr 
                        from  rp_Deck where session_id=p_session_id_in 
                       and position<=35 group by mod(card_name_id,2) )
```

I am getting sqldeveloper warning that select list inconsistent with group by.
And developer gives me solution:

```
select decode(mod(card_name_id,2),0,1,1,2) e_o, count(*) nr 
                        from  rp_Deck where session_id=p_session_id_in 
                       and position<=35 group by mod(card_name_id,2), card_name_id, 2, decode(mod(card_name_id,2),0,1,1,2) )
```

What is difference between these two group by ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, when you use `GROUP BY` in a statement then all the values either need to be:

- constants;
- within aggregation functions; or
- in the `GROUP BY` clause.

SQL Developer does not realise that `decode(value_mod_2,0,1,1,2)` is effectively just adding 1 to the value and does not change the allocation of items to groups so, since it is not either a constant or an aggregation function, it expects the entire function to be in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Personally, I would write it as:

```
select mod(card_name_id,2) + 1 e_o,
       count(*) nr 
from   rp_Deck
where  session_id=p_session_id_in 
and    position<=35
group by mod(card_name_id,2)
```

*(the `+ 1` is a constant so does not need to be in the `GROUP BY` clause)*

The solution SQL Developer proposes is wrong as:

```
select decode(mod(card_name_id,2),0,1,1,2) e_o,
       count(*) nr 
from   rp_Deck
where  session_id=p_session_id_in 
and    position<=35
group by
       mod(card_name_id,2),
       card_name_id,
       2,
       decode(mod(card_name_id,2),0,1,1,2)
```

is effectively the same as just grouping by the finest grained grouping, so:

```
group by card_name_id;
```

Which is not what you want to group by. To be the same as your original query's intended output, it should propose something like:

```
group by
       mod(card_name_id,2),
       decode(mod(card_name_id,2),0,1,1,2)
```

or more simply just:

```
group by
       decode(mod(card_name_id,2),0,1,1,2)
```